# How to make a graphic image responsive in css

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I am having difficulty getting a graphic to behave in responsive design.

The graphic in question is the main image below the menu bar at http://bit.ly/1waPylP

**HTML**

There is no `width` attribute on my graphic.

```
<div class="gc-responsive-div">
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-28 gc-responsive-img" src="/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2014/12/G_HOME.png" alt="Gotham Communications Buttons Graphic" />
</div>
```

**CSS (added as the very last settings in the cascade)**

I am trying to force the image to a max-width of 100%:

```
div.gc-responsive-div,
img.gc-responsive-img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

**My Expectation**

I want the main image to adjust to the viewport's size by shrinking in a responsive fashion width-wise & height-wise versus remaining at the graphic's natural height and width which is overflowing outside the viewpoint. When I view the home page in my large screen monitor, the main graphic (natural width=663px and natural height=616px) appears as designed. Yet when I look at the home page on my iphone the main graphic appears in its original natural width and height to the right of the screen and about 80% of the graphic shows off screen and can't be seen.

To me, responsive means that the graphic shrinks to properly consume the viewpoint and have its aspect ratio adjust to the viewport.

I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

**Screen Shots**

***Large Screen Monitor (looks as designed)***

[image]

***Mobile Device (graphic does not resize)***

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML/CSS code all seems to be fine. Most likely there is **fixed** width set on one/more of the container elements, find it and add/change it to `max-width` too, or adjust it in the media queries if necessary.

Also make sure to have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` or similar responsive meta tags to be set.

Comment: Thanks @Pangloss -- you solved it for me. I had an unrelated div container set to `width:1020px;`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the graphic as a `background-image` and add the property [`background-size:contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to the image container. This will automatically stretch the entire graphic (maintaining aspect ratio) inside the container. Then, if you want your image container to adjust to the viewport, you can use [viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) on it, like setting `width:50vmin;height:50vmin;`.

Comment: So are you saying that in HTML5 and CSS3 there is **no way** to code and style an image to be responsive and adjust to the viewport? It must always be done using `background-images`?

Comment: That was just one suggestion. Of course, you can apply viewport-units on `img` elements as well. They inherently maintain the aspect ratio when either height or width is specified, so you could do something like `img.gc-responsive-img{height:30vh;}`. If it doesn’t work right away, perhaps we should start a Fiddle.